# NSUInteger and NSInteger bridging to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, ios8.4

With Swift 1.2 (yes, I've not switched over to Xcode 7, which is causing me grief), I have the following table view delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.coreDataSource.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
}
```

which causes Xcode 6.4 to give the error:

> Cannot invoke 'numberOfRowsInSection' with an argument list of type
>   '(Int)'

My CoreDataSource method, bridged from Objective-C, has the following .h declaration:

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfRowsInSection: (NSUInteger) section;
```

If I apply a UInt coercion in my table view delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.coreDataSource.numberOfRowsInSection(UInt(section))
}
```

Xcode now gives the error:

> 'UInt' is not convertible to 'Int'

So, it looks to be damed if you do, damed if you don't kind of scenario.

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html), they say:

> Swift bridges NSUInteger and NSInteger to Int.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you wrap the entire return statement in `Int` (return `Int(self.coreDataSource…)`)

Comment: Ohhhhh. Good! It often takes just another set of eyes. I wasn't noticing that there were two Int/UInt conversions taking place. That's got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the entire return statement in `Int` (return `Int(self.coreDataSource…)`).